# Read Cells from output of Format-Table

Tags: powershell, formattable

I have 2 fields that gets pushed via Format-Table

```
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$files  = Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Subject,  Thumbprint -AutoSize
```

I am now trying to read those individual fields again, e.g.

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {    
    if($file[0] -like '*CN=*' ){
        Write-Output $file
        CallOtherMethod $file[1] 
    }
}
```

The above snipped does not work but inicates intent. How can one read a specific output column from the table?

Comment: May I ask why do you want to read output from `Format-Table` instead reading it directly from objects?

Comment: I have to admit it was lack of knowledge - I received the script with Format-Table but now after reading this have realised I cannot use Format-Table

Comment: @PeterPitLock - take a look at what is in the `$Files` variable after you use `Format-Table` on the data. for instance, `$Files[3]` will almost certainly show error text and mention `.FormatData.` as the type. _why?_ because the `Format-*` commands are for _final output to the screen_ OR _final output to a plain text file_. they chop your objects into bits, wrap formatting code around those bits, and then send that out. **_do not use any of the `Format-*` cmdlets if you want to use the output later for anything other than plain text files or screen display._**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already formatted data when `Format-Table` is called. It is not a string that you can compare. If you want to work with the data from `Get-ChildItem` you do not need to send it through the pipeline, or you can use `Select-Object` to only return chosen values.

```
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$files  = Get-ChildItem
# OR
$files  = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Subject,Thumbprint

Foreach ($file in $files) {
    # I think you meant just $file here. You should specify either the subject or thumbprint field.
    if($file.Thumbprint -like '*CN=*' ){
        Write-Output $file
        CallOtherMethod $file 
    }
}
```